# Is there any way to tell whether a park from GeoNames is small or big?

Tags: api, geonames

I have this query for parks in Alabama for example:

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AL&maxRows=100

But it returns all sorts of parks like ballparks, playground, national forests.  Is there a way to distinguish city-block parks from stadiums and from big parks for outdoors?

Also, there is a value that appears named score like this: 34.15653610229492

What is that value?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parks come from a points of interest layer - and points are just that, points.  They don't have an area so there's no way to determine which one is bigger.

You would have to do another query from the points to a polygon layer, or have some similar means of obtaining the area of the park, to filter by size.

The "score" is "how appropriate these results are":

[GeoNames Forum: What is `<score>` tag?](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/1626.page)

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to do the cross-query of point of interest and polygon? Sounds interesting, but I have not seen anything about this.

Comment: @Genadinik The specifics vary with implementation, but you perform a spatial query on a polygon dataset, passing it the points you've collected from the geonames results.  It may have to be to a different service, run elsewhere - I don't know if geonames even has a polygon dataset available.